# Python will not append to list in for loop

Tags: arrays, list, python-3.x, for-loop

i am basically trying to switch around an array of arrays; my initial data are:

```
array = [
    [0,0,0],
    [1,1,1]
    ]
```

the output should be:

```
    [
    [0,1],
    [0,1],
    [0,1]
    ]
```

however what i get is:

```
[]
```

i have tried doing the same thing without the loops but when i introduce them it just wont append!

see code here:

```
array = [
    [0,0,0],
    [1,1,1]
    ]
transformedArray = []
#add rows to transformed
for j in range(0, len(array) - 1):
    transformedArray.append([])
#for each row
for i in range(0, len(array[0]) - 1):
    #for each column
    for k in range(0, len(array) - 1):
        transformedArray[i].append(array[k][i])
```

can you help? i have not found any similar issues online so i am guessing i've missed something stupid!

Comment: Heads up, when you do `range(0, len(array[0]) - 1)` you won't loop over each row, since the `range` stop parameter is *exclusive*. As it stands, though, you'll be getting index errors anyway I believe because you are confusing "rows" and "columns".

Comment: Also, the idiomatic way to do a *transpose* operation is the following: `list(zip(*array))`. And as long as I'm being nitpicky, you are working with *lists* not *arrays*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I figured it out after a bit; I've been looking at it for so long everything is now mixed in my head!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try nesting your loops:

```
array = [
    [0,0,0],
    [1,1,1]
    ]
transformedArray = [[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]]

# iterate through rows
for i in range(len(array)):
   # iterate through columns
   for j in range(len(array[0])):
         transformedArray[j][i] = array[i][j]

for res in transformedArray:
     print(res)
```

returns:

```
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
```

**Edited to Add explanation**:

First, lists are defined as in this code above: `aList = [ ... ]` where an array would be defined as `anArray = numpy.array([...])`, so to the point of the comments above, this is *list* processing in the question, not true python array process. Next, elements are being added to the list by index, so there has to be a place to put them. I handled that by creating a list with 3 elements already in place. The original post would only create the first 2 rows and then have an index failure when the 3rd row is to be created. The nested for loops then iterate through the embedded lists.

Comment: I think it would be worthwhile to be explicit about the bugs you've fixed here, i.e. the off-by-one errors with the `stop` parameters to `range`. As an aside, the idiomatic way of taking the transpose in Python of a list is `list(zip(*array))`.

Comment: sure. First, lists are defined as in this code above: ```aList = [ ... ]``` where an array would be defined as ```anArray = array([...])```, so to the point of the comments above, this is list processing in the question, not true python array process. Next, elements are being added to the list by index, so there has to be a place to put them. I handled that by creating a list with 3 elements already in place. The original post would only create the first 2 rows and then have an index failure when the 3rd row is to be created. The nested for loops then iterate through the embedded lists.

Comment: I meant in the question itself :) I took the liberty of adding this to your answer. You can edit/remove it if you wish.

Comment: I figured it out after a bit as well; basically was looking into the same thing for hours and just couldn't see what I was doing wrong! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by mapping a sequence of index-access operations over all the arrays:

```
for i in range( len( array[0] ) ):
    transformedArray.append( map( lambda x: x[i], array ) )
```